# Collapse various date computations into one function

Tags: android

I have many functions which give number of week of the current year, week of the year
give difference of number of year in the year minus current week of the year and give modulo of their difference by two.

I want to create single method which take two input, the current year("2013") and current date "26/08/2013" and return that their difference modulo 2 is 0 or 1.

```
int totalWeeks = getTotalWeeksInYear(2013);
int currentWeeks = getcurrentweekofYear("26/08/2013");

private int getTotalWeeksInYear(int year) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.DECEMBER);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 31);

    int ordinalDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
    int weekDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1; // Sunday = 0
    int numberOfWeeks = (ordinalDay - weekDay + 10) / 7;
    System.out.println(numberOfWeeks);
    return numberOfWeeks ;

}

private int getcurrentweekofYear(String week) {
    // String dtStart = "26/10/2013"; // Input date from user
    String dtStart = week; 
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/M/yyyy");  
    try {  
        date = format.parse(dtStart);
    } catch (ParseException e) {  
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }
    Calendar calender = new GregorianCalendar();
    calender.setTime(date);

    return calender.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR) ;
}

int diffrence = totalWeeks - currentWeeks;
int remainder = diffrence % 2; 
if (remainder == 0)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "current year weeks is 0", 
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();     
}
else
{
    if (remainder == 1)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "current year weeks is 1" , 
                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
    }
}
```

Comment: i want to replace this many function inside 1 main function which take two parameter  currrent year("2013") and curent date (26/8/2013) and return 1 or zero

Comment: can you please explain " return that there diffrence mode by 2 is 0 or 1"

Comment: see this line    int diffrence= totalWeeks -currentWeeks;
        int remainder = diffrence % 2;

Comment: i m  making diffrence totalnumberofweek in year - currentweeknumber and take mode two theire result

Comment: i want to do all this work in single function which take two parameter  year and current date and return value

Comment: I tossed in what I thought would make a little more sense, let me know if it's wrong.

Comment: Why you can't do by yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int result(int year, String week) {

SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/M/yyyy"); 

Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
cal1.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
cal1.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.DECEMBER);
cal1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 31);

try {  
    Date date = format.parse(week);
} catch (ParseException e) {   
    e.printStackTrace();  
}

Calendar cal2 = new GregorianCalendar();
calender.setTime(date);

return ((( cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) - (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1) + 10) / 7) - cal2.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR) %2) ;

}
```

Though I wonder, there isn't any logic involved so why you couldn't write it.

Comment: no i want to  first subtract totalNumberofWeeks - current week  take mode of result by 2 and check it is zero or 1

Comment: i only want single function whic take two patameter(year and current date) use in method which i pose abpove  result= totalNumberofWeeks- currentweek    take result%2;
return result;

Comment: `function int mod( type year, type date) {
        return getTotalWeeksInYear(year)- getCurrentWeekOfYear(date)%2;`
    }

Comment: i want all of this work in single function just return final value either is 0 or 1

Comment: u again use two diffrent function

Answer (score 2):

You can use Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR in your first function for getTotalWeeksInYear();

```
int xyz(String date){
    // get week of year for the above date, you will get currentWeeks
    // Split String at '/' and get the year
    // Create new calendar with the for December 31 and year from above splitting
    // again get week of year , you will get totalWeeks 
    int diffrence= totalWeeks -currentWeeks;
    int remainder = diffrence % 2;
    Toast.makeText(this, "current year weeks is "+remainder , 
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return remainder ;
 }
```

Comment: u get my point which i say but i want all tewo method inside one mainmethod and take two parameter (intyear,mdate)
return final value

Comment: @user2706686 why you can't do it by your self?

Comment: you can avoid year parameter since its already present in date and besides computation for different year and different date wont make sense so I just used one parameter i.e current date. And then split it using String,split("/") this will give you an array of all tokens and year is definitely the last token so you an use (array.length-1) to get year and do other calculations

Comment: @PankajKumar that is why havent written the code, just an idea

Comment: @RachitMishra You learned from his answer but didn't upvoted :)

Comment: @PankajKumar ooooo esssssssss !